# php jquery - how to show another drop down option if a value is selected in first drop down

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu, echo

I have an upload form, for the first drop down, the category drop down, I want to echo another drop down list (book category) if the option value "book" is chosen

```
<form action="uploadproc1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                     <p> <label for="category"><b>Category</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                 <select name="category" id="category">
                    <option value=""> -- select -- </option>
                    <option value="Accessories">Accessories</option>
                    <option value="Accommodation">Accommodation</option>
                    <option value="Books">Books</option>
                    <option value="Business">Business</option>
                    <option value="Clothing">Clothing</option>
                    <option value="Electronics">Electronics</option>
                    <option value="Furniture">Furniture</option>
                    <option value="Imagery">Imagery</option>
                    <option value="Multi">Multimedia</option>
                    <option value="Tickets">Tickets</option>

                   </select>
        </p>

        <?php IF (category selected==book?){
           echo '<p> <label for="bookcat"><b>Book Category</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>';
                echo '<select name="category" id="category">';
                echo '<option value=""> -- select -- </option>';
                   echo '<option value="Law">Law</option>';
                   echo '<option value="Business">Business</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Optom">Optom</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Engineering">Engineering</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Pharmacy">Pharmacy</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Sciences">Sciences</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Languages">Languages</option>';
                    echo '<option value="English">English</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Maths">Maths</option>';
                    echo '<option value="Other">Other</option>';


                   echo '</select>';
        echo '</p>';

        }

        ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the second dropdown list, but hide it at the beginning:

```
<p id="p_bookcat" style="display: none;">
  <label for="bookcat"><b>Book Category</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
  <select name="bookcat" id="bookcat>
    <option value=""> -- select -- </option>
    <option value="Law">Law</option>
    <option value="Business">Business</option>
    <option value="Optom">Optom</option>
    <option value="Engineering">Engineering</option>
    <option value="Pharmacy">Pharmacy</option>
    <option value="Sciences">Sciences</option>
    <option value="Languages">Languages</option>
    <option value="English">English</option>
    <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
</p>
```

Then add the following jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#category').change(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == 'Books') {
        $('#p_bookcat').show();
      } else {
        $('#p_bookcat').hide();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: thankyou so much but how can i only show the 2nd drop down if the option Books is selected?

Comment: Just change `if ($(this).val() != '')` to `if ($(this).val() == 'Books')` (see my modified code snippet).

Comment: where should i place the jquery code, at the moment it doesnt seem to be working

Comment: If you do not use any Javascript files at the moment, you might simply put the code into your HTML document [wherever you want](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp). Otherwise you might add it - without the opening and closing `<script>` tag - into a .js file of your choice that is loaded somewhere in your HTML document. Note that the paragraph id `p_bookcat` is referenced in the Javascript code (`#p_bookcat`).

Comment: thankyou i have placed in to in a .js file called showcat.js and loaded it by adding this in the <head>, <script type="text/javascript" src="showcat.js"></script>, however it still doesnt seem to work, any ideas?

Comment: Have you load jQuery properly? By the way: You can test the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/KrCB5/

Comment: yeah it works in the js fiddle, i copied the code exactly it doesnt work, any other ideas?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17678/discussion-between-thomas-and-neeko)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#category").change(function() {

        $(this).parent().append('<div><select name="category1" id="category1">'
                        + '<option value="Law">Law</option> '
                        + '<option value="Business">Business</option>'
                        + '<option value=""> -- select -- </option></select></div>');

       });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use onchange()

```
       <form action="uploadproc1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                             <p> <label for="category"><b>Category</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                         <select name="category" id="category" onchange="thefunction(this.value)">
                            <option value=""> -- select -- </option>
                            <option value="Accessories">Accessories</option>
                            <option value="Accommodation">Accommodation</option>
                            <option value="Books">Books</option>
                            <option value="Business">Business</option>
                            <option value="Clothing">Clothing</option>
                            <option value="Electronics">Electronics</option>
                            <option value="Furniture">Furniture</option>
                            <option value="Imagery">Imagery</option>
                            <option value="Multi">Multimedia</option>
                            <option value="Tickets">Tickets</option>

                           </select>
        //<div id='catorsomething'></div> {the new dropdown will display in this div}
```

then in your php script/controller/what ever

```
            <?php
                  public function thefunction(){
            $w=$this->input->post('bookcat');  

             if ($w='Books'){
            echo ' <div id='catorsomething'>
            <p> <label for="bookcat"><b>Book Category</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>';
                            <select name="category" id="category">
                            <option value=""> -- select -- </option>';
                               <option value="Law">Law</option>
                               <option value="Business">Business</option>
                                <option value="Optom">Optom</option>
                                <option value="Engineering">Engineering</option>
                                <option value="Pharmacy">Pharmacy</option>
                                <option value="Sciences">Sciences</option>
                                <option value="Languages">Languages</option>
                                <option value="English">English</option>
                                <option value="Maths">Maths</option>
                                <option value="Other">Other</option>


                               </select>
                    </p></div>
            ';}
                } 
            ?>
```

then below your form action make

```
<div id='catorsomething'></div>
```

I've made my code just like this in CodeIgnitel and it's work (I dont know the correct way but I hope I can help you)